# Does C++ have a smart pointer like unique_ptr with a "destruct before constructing" semantics?

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, unique-ptr, resourcemanager, resource-management

### Problem

Consider this simple class:

```
struct C {
   C(const char* name) : name(name) {
         cout << "constructing " << name  << endl;
   }
   
   ~C() {
       cout << "destructing " << name << endl;
   }
   
   string name;
};
```

I would like to have a pointer to an instance to this class, which is routinely replaced with another instance. However, I would like for the current instance to be destructed *before* the new instance is created.

### Wrong example

If I use a `unique_ptr` in a normal fashion, this does not work:

```
unique_ptr<C> c( new C("the first one"));
c.reset(new C("the second one"));
```

(Undesired) Output:

> constructing the first one
>
> constructing the second one
>
> destructing the first one
>
> destructing the second one

### Ugly example

The desired effect can be achieved as follows:

```
unique_ptr<C> c( new C("the first one"));
c.reset();  // explicitly destruct the first one first
c.reset(new C("the second one"));
```

Output:

> constructing the first one
>
> destructing the first one
>
> constructing the second one
>
> destructing the second one

### Attempted solution

This is my attempt at creating a smart pointer with this behavior.
Does such a smart pointer exist already?

```
template<typename Resource>
class ResourceManager {
  public:
    ResourceManager() {}

    template<typename... Arguments>
    ResourceManager(Arguments&&... args) {
      replace<Arguments...>(std::forward<Arguments>(args)...);
    }

    template<typename... Arguments>    
    void replace(Arguments&&... args) {
      resource.reset();
      resource.reset(new Resource(std::forward<Arguments>(args)...));
    }

  private:
    unique_ptr<Resource> resource;
};

template<typename Resource, typename... Arguments>
ResourceManager<Resource> make_resource_manager(Arguments... args) {
        return ResourceManager<Resource>(args...);
}

int main() {
   //ResourceManager<C, const char*> r("first1");
   auto r = make_resource_manager<C>("first1");
   r.replace("second1");
}
```

Output:

> constructing the first one
>
> destructing the first one
>
> constructing the second one
>
> destructing the second one

**EDIT:** Moved 'Arguments...' template to the function level.

**EDIT 2:** Now forwarding 'Arguments' correctly.

Comment: why not just assign a new one? ptr = make_unique<type>();

Comment: @paulm: Because he does not want two to exist at the same time.

Comment: The question is *why* you cannot have two instances, and you cannot reuse the existing one either… This is somehow a fragile approach in which you can end up with *no* resource at all.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas I am switching between various istream-like objects (ZipEntries), which originate from a single ZipFile object (representing a zip archive with multiple entries). I must make sure that the previous ZipEntry is destroyed before opening a new one.

Comment: It appears to me this is a threading question ignoring the actual issue.

Comment: @WaelJ: Why must the previous one be destroyed first? That looks like a bad interface.

Comment: @Deduplicator Indeed. The library's interface explicitly says "Only one file can be open at a time."

Comment: Container file or contained file? In either case, it's an error-prone interface, and I'm glad not being forced to use it.

Comment: @Deduplicator Sorry, the contained file.

Comment: @Deduplicator Great thanks!
I am not sure what you mean by implicitly defined member-function. Are you referring to implicit constructors?

Comment: @WaelJ: Just reread it all, you've already taken care of it with the rule of 0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Destroying the old state before constructing the new state is avoided in C++ as much as possible, because one cannot provide the strong exception guarantee that way: "The operation succeeds, or it throws an exception **without changing anything**". Thus, the standard library does not have such (I cannot even name a framework adding it).

Naive and wrong copy-constructors sometimes do it though.
If you deliberately want to get that behavior, there's nothing better than coding it for yourself.
But, be really sure that's what you want, and document it for posterity.

Your `ResourceManager` seems mostly to do what you want.
Still, make really sure the method name/class name explicitly calls out your non-standard behavior (neither `ResourceManager` nor `replace` are specific enough).

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing like that in the standard. I am not sure why you want that specific order, either the object is still alive and you can reuse it or else you can end up with the new object failing to be constructed and an empty smart pointer.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the ever unpopular in C++ preprocessor:

```
#define REPLACE_C(ptr,new_value) \
    do { \
        ptr.reset(); \
        ptr.reset(new_value); \
    while(false)

unique_ptr<C> c( new C("the first one"));
REPLACE_C(c, new C("the second one"));
```

Comment: The macros solution is surprisingly more readable and much less error prone :)